# Possible data race with std::thread detected by valgrind

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

A simple threaded program like the following is showing data race in valgrind:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

void fun(void){
    int a = 0;
}

int main(){
    std::thread th1(fun);
    th1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
==20753== 
==20753== Possible data race during write of size 8 at 0x60BC88 by thread #1
==20753== Locks held: none
==20753==    at 0x401B57: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==20753==    by 0x401E5F: std::thread::thread<void (&)()>(void (&)()) (thread:137)
==20753==    by 0x4016DA: main (testmv.cpp:9)
==20753== 
==20753== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #2
==20753== Locks held: none
==20753==    at 0x401B57: std::shared_ptr<std::thread::_Impl_base>::~shared_ptr() (shared_ptr.h:93)
==20753==    by 0x401B9B: std::thread::_Impl_base::~_Impl_base() (in /home/jahid/Git/Github/jpcre2/jpcre2/src/a.out)
==20753==    by 0x403B71: std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >::~_Impl() (in /home/jahid/Git/Github/jpcre2/jpcre2/src/a.out)
==20753==    by 0x4040F0: void __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >::destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >(std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >*) (new_allocator.h:124)
==20753==    by 0x403FFA: void std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > > >::destroy<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >(std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >&, std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >*) (alloc_traits.h:542)
==20753==    by 0x403D8D: std::_Sp_counted_ptr_inplace<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> >, std::allocator<std::thread::_Impl<std::_Bind_simple<void (*())()> > >, (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2>::_M_dispose() (shared_ptr_base.h:531)
==20753==    by 0x4EF8D14: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.21)
==20753==    by 0x4C34DB6: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==20753==  Address 0x60bc88 is 8 bytes inside data symbol "__gcov0._ZNSt10shared_ptrINSt6thread10_Impl_baseEED2Ev"
```

The program is compiled with g++ (5.4.0):

```
g++ -O0 -ggdb3 -fprofile-arcs -ftest-coverage -std=c++11 -pthread testmv.cpp
```

and being tested with `helgrind` tool (*valgrind 3.11.0*):

```
valgrind --tool=helgrind ./a.out
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Works for me with valgrind 3.12, compiled binary with gcc 6.3.1.

Comment: I do however get some errors with clang 3.9, but only if I use libc++ *and* -fprofile-arcs. There's probably some fancy whitelisting going on in the newer versions. Anyways, this is a false positive for sure, so don't worry about it.

Comment: @BaummitAugen : I think it's the `-fprofile-arcs` that's causing this problem, this may have something to do with it: `-fprofile-arcs :   Add code so that program flow arcs are instrumented. During execution the program records how many times each branch and call is executed and how many times it is taken or returns`

Comment: So, just use a build without -fprofile-arcs for helgrind testing?

Comment: `Add code so that..` and `records how many` alludes to shared variables inside the functions to measure the execution frequency.

Comment: @BaummitAugen : yeah, I am doing that right now, :D

Comment: Hooray, we are problem solvers! \o/ =D